# Syntax Error in SQL query. Not able to find mistake

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby

I am writing tests for my database in mysql.

```
con.query(“SELECT  `list`.* FROM `list`  WHERE `list`.`place` = 86 AND `list`.`person` = \"#{person_id}\" AND (( (list.state = 'open' AND num=\"#{num}\") || (list.state = ?) )) AND (list.updated_at > \"2018-06-05\") ORDER BY list.person, list.state='closed' DESC, list.updated_at DESC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 1”)
```

`list` is a table, and `num`, `place`, and `person` are values of a single item from list. I'm also using this in a ruby script.

I get a syntax error. The error message is:

`` You have an error in your SQL syntax check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ‘`?) )) AND (list.update_at > “2018-06-05”)) ORDER BY list.person, or`’ ``

I cannot figure out the issue. Please help me.

Comment: Always, *always* use placeholder values for data. Seeing things like `#{num}` in your query is extremely concerning, that's how you get [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and all the horrible problems that come with that. You're using a placeholder for some values (e.g. `list.state`) but you *must* use placeholders for *all* values. The problem seems to be you're not using the correct method to execute this query, as `query` doesn't support placeholder values, so you need to find the method that does.

Comment: Which Ruby driver for MySQL are you using? If you're using the low-level driver, like the `mysql2` gem, it's very feature limited and hard to use. Instead use a layer like ActiveRecord or [Sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel) which helps abstract some of these low-level concerns away.

Comment: i have not seen this sort of thing and am not sure it's valid: `ORDER BY list.person, list.state='closed' DESC` .. why do you put the equality check in the ORDER BY?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the ORDER BY part of the query

```
ORDER BY list.person, list.state='closed' DESC, list.updated_at DESC
```

list.state should not have an ='closed'

Just try changing the it all to

```
ORDER BY list.person, list.state DESC, list.updated_at DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are using the wrong character for double quotes. You have `“`. Try `"` instead.